# Can we use 'shall have been' + present participle?

Tags: grammar

In the  perfect continuous tense, *shall have been* is not used. Can you tell me why?

When I searched on Google, it showed the form as

> subject + *will have been* + v (ing) + object.

I just want to know  why we are not supposed to use *shall have been* and the reason behind it.

Comment: Because *shall* has gone out of style. You can use it if you want, but you "shall" mark yourself as using outdated language.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you *can* use 'shall have been'. If you google the phrase, you'll see many instances of it in historical quotes.

Most of these quotes date back at least a few decades, so it's fair to say that 'shall have been' is perfectly correct but it has fallen out of use compared to 'will have been'. In modern usage, 'will have been' is much more usual, and 'shall have been' would only be used in very formal writing such as legal contracts.

Incidentally, this is future perfect, not perfect continuous.

Comment: "A few decades back" is no longer "modern usage"? What is it, Old English then?